# Magento Get all products in cart instead of most recent

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I am adapting the modern theme to create a new theme to use.

I need to display *all* the products in the customers basket. I have this code and currently it only displays up to three items. Is there a different command I can use instead of `getRecentItems()` to display all the items in their basket? I tried using `getAllItems()` but this does not seem to do anything.

```
 <?php $items = $this->getRecentItems();?>
        <?php if(count($items)): ?>
            <ol id="cart-header" class="mini-products-list">
                <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('There are no items in your shopping Basket.') ?>
        <?php endif ?>
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Great question, try to link to something that has a similar result of what you are trying to do though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check in `System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart Side Bar`

There is a setting to set the number of products that can be visible in the mini cart.

**Maximum Display Recently Added Item(s)** by default is 3.  Increase it to what you want it to be or rather a high number to always show all products in the cart.

EDIT: To override the default magento behavior based on your comments you could use the following.

```
<?php
    $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
?>
        <?php if(count($items)): ?>
            <ol id="cart-header" class="mini-products-list">
                <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('There are no items in your shopping Basket.') ?>
        <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of anyway that I can do this using a PHP command as this is going to be a theme it will be frustrating for admins if they have to change config to get it to work properly ?

Comment: The setting can be set in the DB using a data install script by looping through all stores and calling `$this->setConfigData('checkout/sidebar/count',[num],'stores',[store id])`. See [`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::setConfigData` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L892). This would *likely* be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Didn't think of setting it with an install script since he's doing frontend work, but this would be the better play if he is packaging the theme with some setup scripts already.

Comment: @ThomasS if product is a configurable product.

Answer (score 1):

The Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar method getRecentItems() accepts a **count** param, just call it in this way to retrieve the full cart items.

```
<?php $items = $this->getRecentItems(10000);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with utility. And thank you for sharing on the Shopping  Cart Side Bar part. I had a module that list the cart items in the checkout page. Here is my code for your reference.

```
$quoteObject = $this->getQuote();
foreach($quoteObject->getAllItems() as $item)
{
  //do what you want here.
}
```

Hope this helps.